Neovim LSP go to declaration and go to definition issue
I have a mapping for "Go to declaration" (gd) and "Go to definition" (gD), but both of them lead to declaration.
Also checked vim.inspect, declarationProvider and definitionProvider are both set to true.
Here is my lsp_config.lua.
require("mason-lspconfig").setup({
    ensure_installed = { "lua_ls", "clangd", "rust_analyzer" },
})

local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

local lsp_defaults = lspconfig.util.default_config

lsp_defaults.capabilities =
    vim.tbl_deep_extend("force", lsp_defaults.capabilities, require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities())

require("lspconfig").lua_ls.setup({
    settings = {
        Lua = {
            diagnostics = {
                globals = { "vim" },
            },
            workspace = {
                library = {
                    [vim.fn.expand("$VIMRUNTIME/lua")] = true,
                    [vim.fn.stdpath("config") .. "/lua"] = true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
})

require("lspconfig").clangd.setup({
    cmd = {
        "clangd",
        "--offset-encoding=utf-16",
    },
})

require("lspconfig").rust_analyzer.setup({})
require("lspconfig").pyright.setup({})

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("LspAttach", {
    group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("UserLspConfig", {}),
    callback = function(ev)
        -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
        vim.bo[ev.buf].omnifunc = "v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc"

        local opts = { buffer = ev.buf }
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gd", vim.lsp.buf.declaration, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gD", vim.lsp.buf.definition, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gi", vim.lsp.buf.implementation, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>wa", vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>wr", vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>wl", function()
            print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
        end, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>D", vim.lsp.buf.type_definition, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>rn", vim.lsp.buf.rename, opts)
        vim.keymap.set({ "n", "v" }, "<space>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "gr", vim.lsp.buf.references, opts)
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<space>f", function()
            vim.lsp.buf.format({ async = true })
        end, opts)
    end,
})

Want to solve this issue to use neovim more efficiently and with more pleasure.
